# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AspNetCoreTodo.Models.ApplicationUser]'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, I need your help

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[AspNetCoreTodo.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'AspNetCoreTodo.Controllers.TodoController'.

Comment: Without any code it would be hard to help you. It seems that you are missing some registrations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you register the Identity, but be sure change `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`. A simple demo like below:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```